# Javascript conditional preventDefault based on callback

Tags: javascript, callback, preventdefault

I am trying to use javascript on a submit button. Upon hitting the submit button, I run a routine that does a remote callback with callback handler h. Basing on the result of h, I'll decide whether or not to proceed with the submit or to preventDefault and stay on the page.

I tried several approaches. First one is to run the submit using jquery after the callback:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  run_func_with_callback(h);
}

h() {
  if (success) {
    $('#submit').submit();
  }
}
```

Another one is trying for an infinite loop until a flag is changed by the call back:

```
callback_flag = 0;

$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
  run_func_with_callback(h);
  while(callback_flag == 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {}, 1000); // I want some form of sleep function here
  }

  if (callback_flag == -1) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

h() {
  if (success) {
    callback_flag = 1;
  } else {
    callback_flag = -1;
  }
}
```

However, neither of these solutions work. First one I guess jQuery just doesn't really work that way. Second one the method I did was not a sleep function and does not behave in the way I need.

Any insights are welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: The only way is to prevent the event immediately and then trigger it again from within the callback if needed.

Comment: Your insight is correct - the second method won't work. You need to trigger the submit form the callback.

Comment: Both of you seem to mention that I should trigger the submit from within the callback as in my first method. However, when I attempt it, the page still freezes and nothing happens. Is there something else I should do or is the syntax different?

Comment: The first approach looks good, with one major detail: what is `success`? I would expect it to be derived from the response, but you don't even _declare_ the response argument to your callback.

Comment: Try the first method, but .submit() the form, not the button.

Comment: *related* http://stackoverflow.com/q/14241980/218196

Comment: @gtr32x: You have to make sure not to end up in an infinite event loop, e.g. by using a flag. I.e. the second time you submit the form, the asynchronous call should not be made and you should not call `.prevenDefault`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sticking with your first approach, would something like this work:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
    if(!success) {
        e.preventDefault();
        run_func_with_callback(h);
    }
    else {
        success = false;
    }
}

h() {
    if (success) {
        $('#submit').click();
    }
}
```

The important thing is to trigger the `click` event in the callback and then use the value of `success` to conditionally execute the submission.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  run_func_with_callback(h);
}

h() {
  if (success) {
    $('#submit').closest("form").submit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope, seems like submit() just does not function for some reason.