# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded - JQuery form submission error

Tags: jquery, form-submit

I have a single input outside the form

```
<input id="BrId" name="BrId" type="text" value="1">
```

HTML Form-

```
 <form id="photoform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="server-side-path">
    <input type="file" id="Photos" name="photo"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="VisitGuid" value="5" />
    <input type="hidden" name="HiddenBrId" id="HiddenBrId" value="" />
    <input type="submit" />
```

JQuery-

```
$('#photoform').on('submit', function (e) { 
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#HiddenBrId').val($('#BrId').val());
     $('#photoform').submit();
});
```

When I click on submit button, form is not being submitted and console says `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Any help?

Comment: where is element with id `BrId`. pls post all relevant code  to the post

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241980/in-jquery-how-to-run-code-with-callback-before-submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form id="photoform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="server-side-path">
    <input type="file" id="Photos" name="photo"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="VisitGuid" value="5" />
    <input type="hidden" name="HiddenBrId" id="HiddenBrId" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" />
</form>

<script>
$('#photoform').on('submit', function (e) { 
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#HiddenBrId').val($('#BrId').val());
     // Change is here
     $('#photoform')[0].submit();
});
</script>
```

**NOTE :**   Please avoid to use ***submit*** and ***reset*** as value of `name` and `id` attribute of any from input.

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual question. You should add why that was happening and how does this solves the issue. Although this solves the issue but not a clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Cause**

```
$('#photoform').on('submit', function (e) { //S-1
. . . 
 $('#photoform').submit(); //This is the cause, it again calls  "S-1" 
});
```

Please explain what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#photoform').on('submit', function (e) { 
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#HiddenBrId').val($('#BrId').val());
     // Change is here
     $('#photoform')[0].submit();
});
```

Comment: It says $('#photoform')[0].submit() is not a function.

Comment: `<input type="submit" />` should be `<input type="submit"  name="submit_btn" />`